# Scroll position affected by internal layout changes inside a page element (Chrome)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/gxas8h7L/5/

Run the fiddle and scroll down until the top of the page intersect one of the red sub-boxes. Observe that the scroll position changes as "world" is periodically toggled. (looks like the whole page jumps up/down)

The toggling does **not** affect the parent height. It's strictly an "component-internal" change.

The effect persist if the gray boxes are absolutely positioned.

The culprit seems to be the center alignment (flex) of the item inside the red box  (`align-items: center;`) Seems like chrome really prefer for "hello" to not move..

Is this a Chrome bug or some strange css-feature?

Does not happen in Firefox.

Tested in Chrome Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) Linux

```js
setInterval(
    () => {
        $(".foo").toggle()
    console.log(document.scrollingElement.scrollTop)
}, 800)
```

```css
#c {
  height: 3000px;
}

#x1 {
  top: 10px;
}
#x2 {
  top: 130px;
}
#x3 {
  top: 260px;
}

.item {
  /* position: absolute; */
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
}

.elem {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c">
  <div id="x1" class="item">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="elem">
        <div>hello</div>
        <div class="foo">world</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="x2" class="item">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="elem">
        <div>hello</div>
        <div class="foo">world</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="x3" class="item">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="elem">
        <div>hello</div>
        <div class="foo">world</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic rule is: If the css box of a child element of the scroll content changes its height **and** currently intersects the top border of the viewport, then the scroll position is adjusted so that the top border of said box stays at the current position.

This make sense insofar as you want incrementally loaded content to push down the page, instead of pushing the page header further up.

Firefox (88.0 Linux 64-bit) does that, too, with the only caveat that if the box changes its height repeatedly then it is ignored after the 10th change.

It does not matter whether the box is a direct or indirect child of the scroll content.

There are very few css properties that affect this behavior, I know only two:

- `display: none` (perhaps unsurprisingly, as no height of the box is computed)
- `flex-direction: column-reverse` on the container (which furthermore has to be flexbox). In this case the behavior is vertically reversed, and a css box height change of a child that intersects the *bottom* border of the viewport causes the scroll adjustment.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it in your jsFiddle by adding `overflow-anchor: none` to a parent element.

[`overflow-anchor:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor) deactivates Chrome's scroll anchoring, which is what you are seeing here. You can read more about what "Scroll Anchoring" is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring

Here's a fixed version of your jsFiddle:

```js
setInterval(
  () => {
    $(".foo").toggle()
    console.log(document.scrollingElement.scrollTop)
  }, 800)
```

```css
#c {
  height: 3000px;
  overflow-anchor: none;
}

#x1 {
  top: 10px;
}

#x2 {
  top: 130px;
}

#x3 {
  top: 260px;
}

.item {
  /* position: absolute; */
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
}

.elem {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c">
  <div id="x1" class="item">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="elem">
        <div>hello</div>
        <div class="foo">world</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="x2" class="item">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="elem">
        <div>hello</div>
        <div class="foo">world</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="x3" class="item">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="elem">
        <div>hello</div>
        <div class="foo">world</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to SO! Consider editing your answer to share your code as a stack snippet.